# May I know the mechanism behind multi-vendor module?

Tags: magento2, multi-vendor

I want to understand mechanism behind multi-vendor module. How we can identity each product from each different product?

How does each product sell by different seller identified and distinguish from other seller? Based on sku or product id?

Comment: did you use 3rd party extension? I think Magento2 does not have marketplace for default ?

Comment: Yes Magento2 don't have default functionality for this and I am used ant 3rd party extension.

Comment: Then please mention those details in Question.

Comment: Thanks & Sorry Aditya, I am not used  any 3rd party extension. I have made typo mistake (and I am used ant 3rd party extension).  I just want to now  1)how we can manage vendor and product mapping? 2)is there separate sku's for multi vendor product? 3)Which one we display on listing page. 4)How we manage different prices, promotion, for same  product with different vendor?

Comment: Okay i'll look into that

Comment: 1)how we can manage vendor and product mapping
Ans - By vendor id and SKU

Comment: 2)is there separate sku's for multi vendor product? - Yes

Comment: 3)Which one we display on listing page.- Ans - which is set as DEFAULT vendor by Admin

Comment: 4)How we manage different prices, promotion, for same product with different vendor - There's vendor panel you can add price and other things from here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84318/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-deepak-shinde).